# python:printing a line for ONLY 1 time in a while loop

Tags: python, loops

I am making a guessing game and I need to program to print the line "only" 1 time in my while True loop. I don't want to put the print("") outside of my loop

```
while True:
       print("I have picked a number between 1 and 100 you can try to guess it.")
```

Comment: `while True: print("abc"); break;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put a `printed` bool:

```
printed = False
while True:
    if not printed:
        print('Hello World!')
        printed = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag

```
flag = True

while True:
    print("I have picked a number between 1 and 100 you can try to guess it.")
    if flag:
        print("only")
        flag = False
```

Comment: @MiloLu exactly what he wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

your while look may have an else clause per the documentation

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement

also look into break statement